# How to set/get the project name in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, fig, docker-compose

I'm trying to either set a docker-compose project name, or to be able to reference it within my config file. Is any of these possible?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm following [this tutorial](http://bradgessler.com/articles/docker-bundler/) so I ended up with a `docker-container.yml` file that reads

```yaml
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
  volumes: 
    - ".:/myapp"
  volumes_from:
    - bundle

db:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017"

bundle:
  image: myapp_web  # <--- this is actually {$project_name}_web being hard-coded
  command: echo Hello
  volumes:
    - /bundle
```

Due to the `image: myapp_web` config, this will only work if the project name itself is `myapp`. This will be true if I'm working on a directory named `myapp` or if I use `docker-compose -p myapp`.

But as soon as someone changes the directory name, this will crash. I'd like to tell docker-compose to use a custom `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` variable without having to pass the `-p fancyname` option.

Another way I could imagine would be to pass some kind of `image: {$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`}_web in the yml file, but I'm really not sure this can be achieved.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this only for referencing the existing image? Any reason why you can't just have `bundle` build `.` again? One of the services (`bundle` or `web`) will be built first. But the second build should be near-instant since it will be cached. The image ID should be the same for both at the point as well.

Comment: You're right, that's actually all I need. You can write this as an answer if you care, or I'll do it myself. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an answer based on my initial comment.

When building multiple services off of the same image it is usually safe to just build it again. In this case, `bundle` can just build `.`. Since you are just building `web` again, it will be cached (thus building quickly) and have the same image ID as well.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [relevant issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/495) on Github for Docker compose that you might want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, as of March 2022 you can use a top-level `name` property to specify the project name in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '2'
name: myapp
services:
  web:
  # ...
```

Useful links:

- [PR in the compose spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/206)
- [GitHub issue about the feature](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745)
- [The updated spec itself](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#name-top-level-element)

I couldn't find this documented on docs.docker.com, though.